# Mouse Events in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have just started an online class on Flash and ActionScript 3.0 and I have been having troubles with mouse events, especially with the `CLICK` class.

So I'm trying to create a basic division calculator, but I can't seem to understand my error with the button. So this is the code that is not working :

```
public function U1A4_DivEtMod() {
    btnSoumettre.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, divise);
}

private function divise(event:MouseEvent):void {
    monFormat.font = "Arial";
    monFormat.size = 20;
    monFormat.bold = true;
    monFormat.color = 0xFFFFFF;

    monMessage.x = 50;
    monMessage.y = 300;

    monMessage.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
    monMessage.border = true;
    monMessage.defaultTextFormat = monFormat;

    var nmb1:int;
    var nmb2:int;
    var repDiv1:int;
    var repDiv2:int;
    var repMod1:int;
    var repMod2:int;
    var nouvMessage:String;

    nmb1=int(entier1.text);
    nmb2=int(entier2.text);
    repDiv1 = nmb1 / nmb2;
    repDiv2 = nmb2 / nmb1;
    repMod1 = nmb1 % nmb2;
    repMod2 = nmb2 % nmb1;

    nouvMessage = (
        nmb1 + " / " + nmb2 + " = " + repDiv1 + "\n" + 
        nmb2 + " / " + nmb1 + " = " + repDiv2 + "\n" +
        nmb1 + " % " + nmb2 + " = " + repMod1 + "\n" +
        nmb2 + " % " + nmb1 + " = " + repMod2 );

    monMessage.text = nouvMessage;
    addChild(monMessage);
}
```

I noticed that my code works when I replace `btnSoumettre` by `this` but I can click wherever I want on the application. I'm trying to make the method only work when the user clicks the button itself.

This is the error Flash is giving me:

> 1061: Appel à la méthode addEventListener peut-être non définie, via la référence de type static Class.

So my version is in French so you guys might not understand but it basically says that the method `addEventListener` is not defined with a static class reference.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Where do you create `btnSoumettre`?

Comment: I think what's happening is that `btnSoumettre` is the name of a class and you need to create an instance of that class, something like `var btn:btnSoumettre = new btnSoumettre();` and then add `btn` to the stage and add the event listener to `btn` via, `btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, divise);`.